# Can I host an MMC snapin in an application

Tags: windows, mmc

Is there a way to host an MMC snapin in an application?  Specifically, we have an "Enterprise Management Application" that we use to manage our applications / services, and we want to add certain functionality to this utility that is already implemented as MMC snapins.  It would be great if we could just host these configured snapins in our existing application instead of having to reinvent the wheel.

I see plenty of info out there on writing MMC snapins, but absolutely nothing on hosting them.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: In order to not "reinvent the wheel" wouldn't it be better to implement your "Enterprise Management Applications" as a MMC snap-in? This is the way it is supposed to work ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This is not something I have tried myself, but it should certainly be possible. If you are trying to host your own snap-in it should be much easier. You didn't mention the MMC version of you snap-in, but MMC and snap-ins communicate using a well-defined API. If you want to host your own snap-ins you have some expectations about how this snap-in will be called. You will have to make those calls from your hosting environment, and perhaps you would even have to do some reverse engineering to fully understand how MMC uses your snap-in.

Comment: I was hoping to host the mmc snapins to save dev time, but since there is no documentation or sample code out there on how to do this, we will probably just reimplement. Creating an mmc snapin host would be an interesting exercise though, and I may do so one day. I will be sure to post the source on the code project if I do!
In any case, thanks for your response.

Comment: I am interested in a solution as well. To complicate matters, I need to host the snap-in in a Java App...

Comment: @Ries: MMC uses either COM or .NET for the API depending on the version. You will have to be able to make either COM or .NET calls from Java to achieve what you want. I know too little about Java to tell you if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a product named JWinExpress at iconage.com that claimed to allow a Java app to be embedded in an MMC snap-in.  I have scoured the internet for this tool, but the website is gone and no one seems to have a mirror of the software